# What exactly is container parameter in onCreateView method in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-inflate, android-viewgroup

When I want to create a simple fragment, usually use following code:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latout, container, false);
  }
}
```

My questions are:
What exactly is container parameter? where it is defined?
Can we see this ViewGroup(container) in XML/Layout Designer?
In this method(onCreateView), what is this ViewGroup(container) id?
In `R.id.x`, to access this ViewGroup(container) What should we replace x with?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call that method, the system does, as part of the [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states).

When a fragment is added to a layout, `onCreateView` will eventually get called, and `container` is the view that holds the fragment. That lets you do things like access the parent's layout parameters, the style/theme applied to it, etc. That's why you pass `container` when you call `inflate`, so it can apply any necessary attributes while inflating the fragment's layout.

Basically don't worry about it, and pass the parent/container when you `inflate` a layout. 99% of the time, that's all you need to know!

Comment: Could you tell me this `container` where and with what will fill?

Comment: I came to the conclusion that `container`  in this method is null !! because I saw the log in below source code:

Comment: `@Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(container == null){
    Log.i("Container", "Container is null !");
      //After run, I see this log. so container parameter is null!
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latout, container, false);
  }`

Comment: if `container` is always null, so why there is in this method?!

Comment: @Mohammad It's not always null, e.g. if you have a ``FrameLayout`` container in an ``Activity``, and you use a ``FragmentTransaction`` to ``add`` your Fragment to that container view, then that ``FrameLayout`` will be passed in as ``container``. So if there's something special you need to do with it, you can. Usually you just pass it to the inflater, whether it's null or not

Comment: Oh! your right! I thought that container is always null. so if we add a fragment in the activity by `FragmentTransaction`, `container` will not be null. Thanks